# Collaboration tools

Tags: penetration-test, tools, vulnerability-assessment

Is there any good alternatives to the lair-framework. I think that was an awesome platform, and unfortunately its not maintained anymore and no more updates to it. But i have tried all other kinds of pentest collaboration tools (Faradaysec, dradis, and a few other ones) but the only one that i can say came close to lair-framework as far as ease of use and very easy to collaborate with other pentesters was attackforge but that was extremely expensive. I was wondering if anyone has seen any other ones out there that are close to attackforge or lair-framework?

Comment: Try asking at [softwarerecs.se]